# Spring upgrade from xml to annotation driven

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I have recently upgraded an old project to latest version of spring
this project has all bean configurations Controller,Service ect defined in an xml configuration.
We would like to change this configuration slowly to annotation driven.
We do not have time to change the entire project to annotation driven quickly but for any new Controllers that we write we would like to use the annotation driven configuration.

Is this possible to have some Controllers annotation driven & some in xml.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

Just use the `@ImportResource` annotation.

See here for more details:

https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-mixing-xml-and-javaconfig/